# Iptables mark incoming packet - vpn routing

Tags: linux, routing, iptables, openvpn, packet

I have connected my home to my workplace for out of house backup reasons through OpenVPN. The connection is working nicely. 
At work I have 5 fixed IP addresses. Now I would like to assign one of these IP addresses to be forwarded to my home machine. I have confirmed packet arrival at my home machine with tcpdump.

The problem is that my default route at home is NOT the tun0 (naturally), but eth0 to my own ISP.
So I created a separate routing table to route my tun0 packets back to where they belong, but do not how to mark the incoming packet which arrive through tun0 with iptables, so I can drive them back.

I do not want any port restrictions, but only what comes from tun0 should leave through tun0.

Comment: The -1 vote is wrong in your case, I redressed it.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Whose -1 vote? What did you redress? If your comment references something, e.g. something somebody wrote, you should quote them.

Comment: @barlop Someone downvoted thi question, I upvoted it. More experienced users can easily see this. Sorry about that.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae  Yes I did see it had been downvoted(my comment to you even implies that it has, so I think you have not understood me). You say you have redressed something but your comment doesn't make sense when there isn't a clear sign of what you 'redressed'.

Comment: @barlop This is a serious question. I do not think it can be done with iptables, but it can be done with policy routing, an advanced feature which, while well-known to experts, is still not widely known to beginners. Also, the question has a new twist, because you need to understand which routing table will be affected by openvpn (which AFAIK, only acts on the *main* table). So I have justified my redressing, I am only waiting for the downvoter to justify his action.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I don't know why it was downvoted, maybe somebody thought it was an XY question(a rash judgement) and that it deserved it. I see, by redressing you meant done in your answer. Yes I see that.  I don't know whether iptables can. It can  do some things that might apply, it has a REDIRECT keyword.   http://serverfault.com/questions/318960/easy-way-to-edit-the-traffic-coming-from-a-tcp-host-linux    There is also a 'mangle' keyword for modifying a packet.  I don't know if he can modify an IP or anything else to get what he wants, with  iptables.

Comment: this on packet mangling (with iptables), http://mylinuxbook.com/utilizing-iptables-with-linux-for-network-packet-mangling/  this on REDIRECT  (with iptables) http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-setup-transparent-proxy-squid-howto.html   I don't know if they help. But I see mention of marking a packet in his question and an answer involving making a route(without iptables) so they may be relevant re what iptables can do and whether it can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a matter of marking packets with iptables, but of using two distinct routing tables. You need to do that because you will have two default gateways, and this is possible only if you have two totally  distinct routing tables, with appropriate rules defining when to apply each.

The normal procudere for setting up a two-routing table system is as follows:

First, create two tables (replace NAME1 and NAME2 with names which mean something to you, same with IP1, DEV1, and so on):

```
  echo 200 <NAME1> >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
  echo 201 <NAME2> >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Add a gateway to each routing table (if needed):

```
  ip route add <NET1> dev <DEV1> src <SRC1> table <NAME1>
  ip route add <NET2> dev <DEV2> src <SRC2> table <NAME2>
```

Then a default route:

```
 ip route add default via <IP1> table <NAME1>
 ip route add default via <IP2> table <NAME2>
```

Then the rules to select the route table based on the source address:

```
 ip rule add from <IP1> table <NAME1>
 ip rule add from <IP2> table <NAME2>
```

In your case, this is even simpler because starting the VPN will automatically set up your main routing table for you, and you only need to do this for the other routing table.  In the above rule, IP1 should be the IP address of the tun/tap interface, and IP2 the IP address of the other interface (that may be eth0 or wlan0, or whatever).

As for other applications which start a connection from your pc, you will just have to *bind* them to either NIC.

EDIT:

Now that I see the picture of the setup you are trying to realize, I see that the solution I proposed above is not correct because you do not wish to have all of your traffic routed through the VPN, only that intended for the other LAN. This is **much easier**.

Forget everything about two routing tables, and policy routing. Erase the second routing table. Start your VPN, make sure neither the client nor the server contains a statement containing the words *redirect-gateway df1*. Then, on your home server, issue the following commands as sudo:

```
  ip route add 192.168.57.0/24 via 192.168.162.5 
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

while on your work router, issue, again as sudo, these two commands:

```
  ip route add 192.168.112.0/24 via 192.168.162.9
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

The capitals, where present, are required.

Comment: Sorry, ran out of the 5 minute edit rule. Trying to get my head round this. What I have done till now: Skiiped the frst part and routing information because that should be my main routing table that is in place and working well. So just created one extra table 200 and named it fromvpn. added a default route. What troubles me is: that I do not know <NET1>, can I add 0.0.0.0? Can <SRC1> be an interface name or is it a network? Also the from <IP1> does not work for me. At least I think it does not, because tcpdump shows me the foreign public ip arriving at my router and not the vpn ip.

Comment: Ran out of characters. I did a little drawing what I like to achieve. I'd like to get the green route, but I have the red one. [link]http://tinypic.com/r/r0c9s4/8

Comment: @Tom Please see the Edit to my answer, it addresses the problem in your setup.

Comment: Yipppie! U da man! Thanks. Working like a charm! (Sorry but don't have enough reputation to up your answer)

Comment: @Tom But you can accept it, and that is just as good.